# Javascript - adding <br> to callout using document.createElement not showing

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a callout using the Apple MapKit JS using `document.createElement` which is working by adding elements from an array that contains the data. If I add `p` or `a` elements these display correctly, but when I try and add `br` elements these aren't showing. I don't want to have so much space between the lines on the callout - here's how it currently looks:

[image]

As you can see the space between the lines is quite large and it's not showing the element between the Phone and the contact lines. Here's the code for the callout that I'm creating:

```
// Landmark annotation callout delegate
var calloutDelegate = {
// Return a div element and populate it with information from the
// annotation, including a link to a review site.
calloutContentForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "review-callout-content";

    var link = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    link.href = annotation.landmark.url;
    link.textContent = "website";   

    var phone = element.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
    //phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;
    phone.textContent = `Phone: ${annotation.landmark.phone}`;

    var addLine = element.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    addLine.textContent = 'Opening Hours Coming Soon!';

    var contact = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    contact.href = annotation.landmark.url2;
    contact.textContent = "contact";

    // Add more content.
    element.style.width = "240px";
    element.style.height = "100px";
    return element;
}
```

I was hoping that using `br` instead of `p` would reduce the space between the lines but now it's not showing the 'Opening Hours Coming Soon!' line at all which has stumped me.

Comment: `<br />` is a self-closing tag that has no content. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: The `br` tag is for adding a line break, not content. You could use a `p` and style it, or you could use a `span` (probably also with _some_ styling).